# Wortstellung von „Weder... noch“ + „dass“

Tags: conjunction

Was ist die richtige Wortstellung für „weder... noch“ mit „dass“? Gilt „weder dass... noch dass...“?

Z.B:

> Ich werde nicht bestreiten, weder dass Trump rassistisch ist, noch dass seine Anhänger auch rassistisch sind, noch dass viele Anhänger Trump mögen, gerade weil Trump rassistisch ist.

Ist das richtig? Gibt es andere Möglichkeiten? (Mein Lehrer hat „dass weder... noch dass... noch dass“ vorgeschlagen.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dein Satz ist nicht ganz richtig:

> Ich werde **nicht** bestreiten, **weder** dass Trump rassistisch ist, **noch**
>   dass seine Anhänger auch rassistisch sind, **noch** dass viele Anhänger
>   Trump mögen, gerade weil Trump rassistisch ist.

Hier ist das "nicht" zu viel. Besser wäre, hier kein "weder ... noch" zu verwenden:

> Ich werde **nicht** bestreiten, **dass** Trump rassistisch ist, **oder dass**
>   seine Anhänger [es] sind, **oder dass** ...

Oder, das "weder" anstelle von "nicht" zu verwenden:

> Ich werde **weder** bestreiten, **dass** Trump rassistisch ist, **noch** dass ...

Dieser Satz klingt wegen der Ähnlichkeit von "werde" und "weder" eher ungewöhnlich, man würde stattdessen sagen:

> Ich bestreite **weder**, dass ...

Der Vorschlag deines Lehrers:

> Ich werde nicht bestreiten, **dass weder** Trump rassistisch ist, **noch**
>   seine Anhänger rassistisch sind ...

Diese Version des Satzes bedeutet etwas ganz anderes: Jemand hat gesagt, dass Trump und seine Anhänger *nicht* rassistisch seien, und du wirst nicht bestreiten, *was er gesagt hat*.
Du sagst hier also, Trump sei *nicht* rassistisch. In den anderen Sätzen sagst du dagegen, dass er rassistisch sei. "Noch dass" kann man in diesem Satz nicht verwenden, das wäre ungrammatisch.

Comment: Kein Komma vor oder. ;)

Comment: Man kann das Komma weglassen, aber in diesem Fall macht es den Satz lesbarer.

Comment: Dieses Komma ist nicht optional. Man macht definitiv weniger Kommafehler, wenn man vor "und" und "oder" nie ein Komma setzt. Auch wenn es in der Tat manchmal richtig ist. Manchmal, aber nicht hier.

Comment: [Die Frage, ob Komma oder nicht, liegt also letztendlich im Ermessen des Schreibenden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/komma-bei-mehrteiligen-nebensatzeinleitungen)

Comment: Nur dass dein Link sich auf ein ganz anderes Komma bezieht. Da wird kein Komma vor ein "oder" gesetzt. Du solltest dich lieber auf das [Regelwerk §72](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf72) beziehen, dann bist du auf der richtigen Spur. Gleichrangige Teilsätze werden **nicht** mit Komma voneinander abgetrennt. Ausnahme (§73), wenn die Sätze selbstständig sind, dann optionales Komma. Ist hier aber nicht der Fall. Also kein Komma.

Comment: In keiner unserer Referenzen wird dieser genaue Fall ("oder dass") genannt, aber da wir uns einig sind, dass die Variante ohne Komma korrekt (aber schwer verständlich) ist, kann das Komma von mir aus weg.

Answer (score 1):

Ich finde den Satz, so wie er in der Frage steht, nicht wirklich gut formuliert. Besser wären aus meiner Sicht folgende Alternativen:

> Ich werde weder bestreiten, dass Trump rassistisch ist, noch dass seine Anhänger auch rassistisch sind, noch dass viele Anhänger Trump mögen, gerade weil Trump rassistisch ist.
>
> Ich werde nichts bestreiten. Weder dass Trump rassistisch ist, noch dass seine Anhänger auch rassistisch sind, noch dass viele Anhänger Trump mögen, gerade weil Trump rassistisch ist.
>
> Ich werde nicht bestreiten, dass Trump rassistisch ist, noch dass seine Anhänger auch rassistisch sind, noch dass viele Anhänger Trump mögen, gerade weil Trump rassistisch ist.